# VBA: How to create a new row in a table which copies format and formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a table (customer complaints). I want to create a macro that allows the user to add a new row each time there is a new complaint. The row should copy the formatting, formulas and data validation options from the row above, but not any hard coded items. I have created this code, but it is copying the whole row, not the formulas and formatting and data validation only.

Any suggestions?

```
Sub Add_new_item()

  ' Go to last cell
  Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

  ' Copy formula from cell above
  Rows(Selection.Row - 1).Copy
  Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a `.ClearContents` after inserting the new row:

```
Sub Add_new_item()

    ' Go to last cell
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    ' Copy formula from cell above
    Rows(Selection.Row - 1).Copy
    Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows(Selection.Row).ClearContents

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Also it's best to end with a `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to clear the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

An easier non-VBA solution would be to use a Table.  If all you're doing is retaining the formatting and formulas, a Table will do everything for you with no code required.  As long as your data has unique column headings, you should be good to go.  Select the range of data you want as your Table (including column headings), then click ctrl+t.  A dialog will display asking you to select the range you want to use (will already have your selection in place) and a "My table has headers" checkbox to indicate if you want to use column headings (check this box).  Click "OK".  You now have a Table.  Simply clicking in the first empty cell and starting to type will add your new row with all the formatting and formulas your prior rows have.

[Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)